# How can I make rhythmbox open maximised initially?

Tags: rhythmbox, default

When I launch Rhythmbox I always have to go to the panel indicator and choose to show rhythmbox. I have looked at the preferences and see no option to make it show as default. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter this: `gconf-editor`
- apps > rhythmbox > plugins > status-icon
- check `window-visible`

[image]

OR

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter this:

`gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/rhythmbox/plugins/status-icon/window-visible true`

Comment: Sweet! That works a treat fluteflute thankyou.